# Table Id field automatically append with table name that produce invalid column name

Tags: entity-framework, ef-core-2.2

I have table Categories With Id column when insert occur is shows it shows errorSqlException: Invalid column name 'CategoriesId'.

```
 public partial class Categories
    {
        public Categories()
        {
            CategoryTabs = new HashSet<CategoryTabs>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int? ParentId { get; set; }
        public int? SeasonId { get; set; }
        public int? Levels { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public virtual Seasons Season { get; set; }
        public List<Categories> children { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<CategoryTabs> CategoryTabs { get; set; }
    }

 public partial class CategoryTabs
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int? CategoryId { get; set; }
        public int? TabId { get; set; }
         public virtual Categories Category { get; set; }
        public virtual Tabs Tab { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CategoriesId` is the conventional name for the Foreign Key property/column associated with the one-to-many self relationship introduced by

```
public List<Categories> children { get; set; }
```

collection navigation property inside `Categories` entity.

Looking at the entity model, most likely the idea was to use the `ParentId` for that purpose. Since it doesn't match EF Core naming conventions, it has to be mapped explicitly by using either `ForeignKey` data annotation:

```
[ForeignKey(nameof(ParentId))]
public List<Categories> children { get; set; }
```

or fluent API inside `OnModelCreating` override:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Categories>()
    .HasMany(e => e.children)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.ParentId);
```